# The infinite loop space associated to the spectrum associated to a special $\Gamma$-space

Tags: simplicial-stuff, algebraic-k-theory, stable-homotopy-theory, spectra

I am currently reading M. Mandel's paper `*An Inverse $K$-theory Functor*' to extract some results I may wish to use in my masters research project, and I am stuck on one particular claim.

On the top of the 3rd page Mandel claims that given a special $\Gamma$-space $X$, its associated infinite loop space is the group completion of $X(\mathbf{1})$.

Now, I know that given a special $\Gamma$-space $X$ the pointed simplicial set $X(\mathbf{1})$ can be equipped with a monoidal structure, up to homotopy. I also know what it means to (homotopy) group complete such a monoidal structure. Furthermore, I know that to $X$ we can associate a spectrum $X(\mathbb{S}^0),X(\mathbb{S}^1),X(\mathbb{S}^2),... $ (as constructed in Bousfield and Friedlander's Paper `*Homotopy Theory of $\Gamma$-Spaces, Spectra, and Bisimplicial Sets*'), which is stably equivalent to the $\Omega$-spectrum
\begin{align}
\Omega X(\mathbb{S}^1), \quad X(\mathbb{S}^1), \quad X(\mathbb{S}^2), \quad ...
\end{align}
The $0$-th space of this $\Omega$-spectrum is, of course, the $0$-th space of an infinite loop space.

My question is: Why is the space $\Omega X(\mathbb{S}^1)$ the group completion of $X(\mathbf{1})$?

I believe that  $X(\mathbb{S}^0) \cong X(\mathbf{1})$, and we hence have the composite map
\begin{align}
X(\mathbf{1})
\to
\mathbf{Hom}_*(\mathbb{S}^1,X(\mathbb{S}^1))
\to
\mathbf{Hom}_*(\mathbb{S}^1,S |X(\mathbb{S}^1)| ) =: \Omega X(\mathbb{S}^1).
\end{align}
But I don't see any argument as to why the $X(\mathbf{1}) \to \Omega X(\mathbb{S}^1)$ is a group completion. What am I missing?

Thanks :)

Comment: Since posting this question I've noticed that the way one equips the pointed simplicial set $X(\mathbf{1})$ with a monoidal structure is not as easy as I originally thought (perhaps one needs to take $X(\mathbf{1})$'s fibrant replacement $Ex^{\infty}(X(\mathbf{1}))$?).

Also, I've now employed a different approach to my thesis, so I no longer need help with my posted question. Although an answer to it would still be interesting to see.